# Hide Custom Button on Layout in Community

Tags: community, custom-button

So my task is to remove Custom button for some Permission sets in **Community**.

[image: Community Lead Layout]

So this is how it looks. We want to hide Reassign button, which is Custom Button that invokes flow. And I need to hide it only for some **Permission sets**

1. I can not create new Page layout dedicated for this because Layout assigments are based on Profile, and I need based on Permission sets
2. I can not deny "Run Flow" permission for those Sets because other buttons are as well Flows.

The only solution I can see is, to **"Edit CSS"** in Community and **hide** that button. But is it even possible? Because first of all I need to **find** out the **Permission set** of current user

Answer (score 1):

The one thing you can do is -

> You can create a **Custom Permission** and add that to your permission set
> and then you can control the button visibility in **Lightning Record
> Page** based on Custom Permission.

The other thing you can do is -

> Go to flows from setup. And, then click on the drop-down there and
> select **Edit Access** and remove the profile from that particular
> flow for which you don't want to run. You can see this in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Hey Gaurav, thanks for reply, but about the second solution, it would not work for us as we need to handle it trough permission sets.
The first one, we need solution for Communities

Comment: Are you using any specific record page layout in the community?